# How to show <app name> instead via #ios in google+ in ios

Tags: ios, share, google-plus

I have used below code to post text using google+

```
  [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
  [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Hi friends from ios"];            
  [shareBuilder open];
```

I have problem with this is after sharing post on google+, at right corner it show #ios instead my app name. How i can show my app name instead #ios. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The #hashtag at the edge of a Google+ post is something that is automatically created in all kinds of posts on Google+ based on the contents of the post. This has nothing at all to do with your app, but something that thee Google+ stream does automatically if it thinks it recognizes subjects in a post.

You won't see your app name displayed automatically. If you want to prefill the suggested text with something like "Hi friends from iOS. #myappname" then the user might choose to retain your hashtag, but you're not going to see anything next to the share like what Facebook does.